# $\mathcal B=\sigma(\mathbb B)$ implies $f^{-1}(\mathcal B)=\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathbb B))?$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

I'm having a little difficulty proving the following exercise: Suppose $(X, \mathcal A)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B)$ are two measurable spaces, and $f: X \to Y$ is measurable.  Suppose also that $\mathcal B$ is generated by a class $\mathbb B$ of sets in $Y$, i.e. $\mathcal B=\sigma(\mathbb B)$.  Let $f^{-1}(\mathcal B)=\{f^{-1}(E):E\in \mathcal B\}$, and $f^{-1}(\mathbb B)=\{f^{-1}(E):E\in \mathbb B\}$, i.e. roughly the "inverse images" of $\mathcal B$ and $\mathbb B$ under $f$, respectively.  I want to show that $f^{-1}(\mathbb B)$ is a generating class for $f^{-1}(\mathcal B)$, i.e. $f^{-1}(\mathcal B)=\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathbb B)).$

Here's what I tried.  I relied on the following two facts about inverse images:

$$f^{-1}(E^c)=(f^{-1}(E))^c$$
$$f^{-1}(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} f^{-1}(E_n)$$

For any $A\in f^{-1}(\mathcal B)$, there exists $E\in \mathcal B$ such that $A=f^{-1}(E).$  Since $\mathcal B=\sigma(\mathbb B)$, $E$ is a countable sequence of set operations (complements & unions) on sets in $\mathbb B$.  For example, suppose $E=(B_1\cup B_2)^c$ for some $B_1, B_2\in \mathbb B.$  Then

$$A=f^{-1}(E)=f^{-1}((B_1\cup B_2)^c)=(f^{-1}(B_1\cup B_2))^c=(f^{-1}(B_1)\cup f^{-1}(B_2))^c.$$

Therefore $A$ can be written as a sequence of set operations on $f^{-1}(B_1)$ and $f^{-1}(B_2).$  Hence $A\in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathbb B)).$

Conceivably, this argument applies to any $E$ that can be produced by a countable sequence of set operations on sets in $\mathbb B$.  However, I find it difficult to formalize this argument with mathematical expressions/equations.  Is the above argument correct?  Is there a way to formalize it, or is there a better (more rigorous) proof?
 Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to formalize the idea that any $E \in \mathbb{B}$ can be obtained by applying countably many set operations on sets of $\mathbb{B}$, here is a useful lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $\mathbb{B}_0 = \mathbb{B}$, and we define $\mathbb{B}_{\alpha}$ for countable ordinals $\alpha > 0$ recursively by
>
> $$ \mathbb{B}_{\alpha} = \{ E^c : E \in \cup_{\beta < \alpha} \mathbb{B}_{\beta} \} \cup \{ \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n : E_n \in \cup_{\beta < \alpha} \mathbb{B}_{\beta} \}. $$
>
> Then the union $\cup_{\alpha} \mathbb{B}_{\alpha}$ over all countable ordinals $\alpha$ is exactly $\sigma(\mathbb{B})$.

Indeed, we check that

- If $E \in \mathbb{B}_{\alpha}$, then $E^c \in \mathbb{B}_{\alpha+1}$. This shows that $\cup_{\alpha} \mathbb{B}_{\alpha}$ is closed under complement.
- By the transfinite induction, $\mathbb{B}_{\alpha} \subseteq \sigma(\mathbb{B})$ for all countable ordinals $\alpha$. So $\cup_{\alpha} \mathbb{B}_{\alpha} \subseteq \sigma(\mathbb{B})$.
- To show that $\cup_{\alpha} \mathbb{B}_{\alpha}$ is closed under countable union, it suffices to notice that for any sequence $(\beta_n)$ of countable ordinals there exists a countable ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\beta_n < \alpha$ for all $n$.

So it follows that $\cup_{\alpha} \mathbb{B}_{\alpha}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra satisfying $\mathbb{B} \subseteq \cup_{\alpha} \mathbb{B}_{\alpha} \subseteq \sigma(\mathbb{B})$. By the minimality of $\sigma(\mathbb{B})$, the desired conclusion follows.

---

As an alternative argument,

1. It is easy to check that $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathbb{B}))$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Since $f^{-1}(\mathbb{B})$ is a subset of this $\sigma$-algebra, we have $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathbb{B})) \subseteq f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathbb{B}))$.
2. To show the other direction, we define $\mathcal{F}$ by

   $$ \mathcal{F} = \{ E \in \sigma(\mathbb{B}) : f^{-1}(E) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathbb{B})) \}. $$

   Then $\mathbb{B} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ and it is routine to check that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under both complement and countable union. So $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and by the minimality we have $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(\mathbb{B})$. This proves the reverse direction $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathbb{B})) \subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathbb{B}))$ .

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This is exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function.

The following rules are not difficult to prove (preimages are very coöperative).

> rule 1: If $\mathcal C\subseteq\wp(Y)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra then so is $f^{-1}(\mathcal C)$.
>
> rule 2: If $\mathcal D\subseteq\wp(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra then so is $\{A\in\wp(Y)\mid f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal D\}$

On base of the first rule it can be shown that: $$\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))\subseteq f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))$$

It is evident the $f^{-1}(\mathcal C)\subseteq f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))$ and the first rule tells us that we are allowed to conclude that $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))\subseteq f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))$ as required.

On base of the second rule it can be shown that: $$f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))\subseteq\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))$$

Applying rule2 on $\mathcal D=\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))$ we find that $\mathcal C\subseteq\{A\in\wp(Y)\mid f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal D\}$ and we conclude that $\sigma(\mathcal C)\subseteq\{A\in\wp(Y)\mid f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal D\}$ hence $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))\subseteq\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))$.

Proved is now that: $$\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))= f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))$$

You can apply that on $\mathcal C=\mathbb B$.