# sigma algebra generated by a set which being a subset of another generating set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a question regarding sigma algebra generated by a set.

It is from 5.4b) from here:
http://stat.math.uregina.ca/~kozdron/Teaching/Regina/451Fall13/Handouts/451lecture05.pdf

Basically I know that given a sigma algebra (say $F= ${$F_1, F_2, ...$} ) of a set $\Omega$, I have that for any subset $\Omega_i \subset \Omega$, the collection of sets $F \cap \Omega_i$ also being a sigma algebra (this result is from 5.4a)).

My question is if I know that a given set say $C$ generates the sigma algebra $F$, i.e. $\sigma(C)=F$, how do I show that the sets $F \cap \Omega_i$ is generated by $C \cap \Omega_i$? i.e. $\sigma(C \cap \Omega_i) = F\cap \Omega_i$ where $F \cap \Omega_i$ is a collection of subsets.

I was able to show that $\sigma (C \cap \Omega_i)$ is a subset of $F \cap \Omega_i$. Because $F \cap \Omega_i$ is a sigma algebra that contains the collection of sets $C \cap \Omega_i$ , so therefore obviously we have $\sigma(C \cap \Omega_i)$ being a subset of $F \cap \Omega_i$ since $\sigma(C \cap \Omega_i)$ denotes the INTERSECTION of all sigma algebra that contains the set $C \cap \Omega_i$.

So I have $\sigma(C \cap \Omega_i) \subseteq F\cap\Omega_i$.

My problem is to show the other way i.e. show that $F\cap\Omega_i \subseteq \sigma(C \cap \Omega_i) $.

I was able to start with this:

I have that $F \cap\Omega_i \subseteq \sigma(C) \cap \Omega_i$  because $F$ is a subset of $\sigma(C)$ , and hence $F \cap\Omega_i \subseteq \sigma(C) \cap \Omega_i$, but that is not really what I want to show. I think I need little more step to prove $F\cap\Omega_i \subseteq \sigma(C \cap \Omega_i) $, but I got kind of stuck.

Could someone give me some hints. Also if the steps above so far are all correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it be that $\langle\Omega,\mathcal F\rangle$ is a measurable space and that $f:\Omega'\to\Omega$ denotes a function.

Moreover let it be that $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal F$ such that $\mathcal F=\sigma(\mathcal C)$.

Then  it can be shown that:$$f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))=\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))\tag1$$

In the special case where $\Omega'\subseteq\Omega$ and $f$ denotes the inclusion application of $(1)$ results in:$$\{\Omega'\cap F\mid F\in\mathcal F\}=\sigma\left(\{\Omega'\cap C\mid C\in\mathcal C\}\right)$$ which is exactly what you are after.

Familiarity with $(1)$ is in my view a "must" in measure theory.

For a proof of it have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2383237/75923).

---

**edit**:

Let $\Omega'\subseteq\Omega$ and let's denote $\mathcal{C}'=\left\{ A\cap\Omega'\mid A\in\mathcal{C}\right\} $
and $\mathcal{F}'=\left\{ A\cap\Omega'\mid A\in\mathcal{F}\right\} $
where $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\wp\left(\Omega\right)$ and $\mathcal{F}=\sigma\left(\mathcal{C}\right)$.

It is not difficult to prove that $\mathcal{F}'$ is a $\sigma$-algebra,
and this with $\mathcal{C}'\subseteq\mathcal{F}'$. This allows the
conclusion $\sigma\left(\mathcal{C}'\right)\subseteq\mathcal{F}'$ and this part you had done yourself allready.

Now let $\mathcal{A}:=\left\{ A\in\wp\left(\Omega\right)\mid A\cap\Omega'\in\sigma\left(\mathcal{C}'\right)\right\} $.

Again it is not difficult to prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra,
and this with $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$. This allows the conclusion
$\mathcal{F}=\sigma\left(\mathcal{C}\right)\subseteq\mathcal{A}$.
That means that $A\cap\Omega'\in\sigma\left(\mathcal{C}'\right)$
for every $A\in\mathcal{F}$ and states that $\mathcal{F}'\subseteq\sigma\left(\mathcal{C}'\right)$.

---

If $f:\Omega'\to\Omega$ denotes the inclusion then $\mathcal C'=f^{-1}(\mathcal C)$ and $\mathcal F'=f^{-1}(\mathcal F)=f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))$ so in the first part it is shown that $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))\subseteq f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))$ and in the second part that $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal C))\subseteq\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal C))$.

For completeness: $$f^{-1}(\mathcal C):=\{f^{-1}(A)\mid A\in\mathcal C\}=\{\{\omega\in\Omega'\mid f(\omega)\in A\}\mid A\in\mathcal C\}\tag2$$

So if $f:\Omega'\to\Omega$ is prescribed by $\omega\mapsto\omega$ (i.e. inclusion) then we can expand $(2)$ with:$$=\{\{\omega\in\Omega'\mid \omega\in A\}\mid C\in\mathcal C\}=\{A\cap\Omega'\mid A\in \mathcal C\}=\mathcal C'$$

Comment: Hi drhab, could you elaborate little bit more about what you mean when you say "f denotes the inclusion....", what does "f denotes the inclusion" means?  sorry for my stupidity. Also I am just wondering the function "f" here could means any "set operations", "mapping" , because so far I have only learned that f as a function can map something from the domain to the range. But does it mean the function "f" is actually more than mapping? for example, the function "f" could mean "set operations" like taking complement, taking union, taking intersection?

Comment: because I got kind of lost how to use "inclusion", and application of (1) to arrive at the equation you have there. Sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: Here there are two sets $\Omega_0,\Omega$ and $f:\Omega_0\to\Omega$ is a function in the usual sense of the word. If $\Omega_0\subseteq\Omega$ then $f:\Omega_0\to\Omega$ is the inclusion of $\Omega_0$ if it is prescribed by $\omega\mapsto\omega$. In that case a preimage under $f$ of some $F\subseteq\Omega$ will take the shape $f^{-1}(F)=\{\omega\in\Omega_0\mid f(\omega)\in F\}=\{\omega\in\Omega_0\mid \omega\in F\}=\Omega_0\cap F$.

Comment: Hi drhab, thanks for your response. I understand little better. But it is kind of difficult to associate the proof of sigma algebra generated by a set with the "inclusion function". What I mean is it is kind of hard to understand the intuition behind why all of a sudden one would think of the "inclusion" function $\omega \mapsto \omega$ when trying to prove 5b). I think I need little more time to understand. Also you have shown what $f^{-1}(F)$ is , but I still have to figure out the right-hand side (i.e. why $\sigma (f^{-1}(C))$ equal the right side of your formula). I am still digesting.

Comment: I have added a direct proof.

Comment: Hi drhab, I think I fully understand the proof in your "edit" part. It is very clear. But once I looked at the part after "edit", i.e. the part with all the $f^{-1}(C), f: \Omega_{0} \mapsto \Omega $, then I got confused. I think the proof under "edit" is so clear and already answer my questions. But the alternative answer i.e. those with the inverse function, (i.e. the equation (1) in your very first answer) drives me kind of crazy and confused. I am still digesting the equation (1) and the inverse function thing since it is so important in Measure Theory. It is good to know another way.

Comment: I will try to understand slowly and carefully the explanations involving those inverse mapping first and will try to memorize equation (1) you put there. Because equation (1) you put there seems very important and it is kind of a super short-cut for proving things.

Comment: For certainty: there is no inverse function here. The notation $f^{-1}(C)$ stands for the preimage of $C$ under $f$, i.e. $f^{-1}(C):=\{\omega\in\Omega_0\mid f(\omega)\in C\}$. Don't confuse this with $f^{-1}$ as inverse function. Inverse functions are absent in my answer.

Comment: The answer without the "inverse function" are perfect and I can fully understand since I was also looking for similar ways of proving that. But the part with "inverse function" drives me little bit confused and it will take me sometimes to understand and make use of. But it seems I understand more and little better now for those parts that involved the "inverse mapping".

Comment: Oh sorry I may be little bit confused. I will try to read more carefully the part with preimage and will get back here with more questions later. My background is kind of weak in measure theory or real analysis.

Comment: But you already answer my questions perfectly. And you also introduced the part with "pre-image" too which is another way of "proving" what I was trying to prove. It is great that I learn about this because equation 1 seems important. Thanks for your help. I will digest more first.

Comment: If your main questions are answered, then you can accept this answer, right? Make it a custom to do that. I see that uptil now you posed $10$ questions and only made one acceptance. Your standards might be too high ;-).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Yes i accepted now. Haha

Comment: Hi drhab, I just read your answer more carefully. Actually in the very first line of your answer, you actually said "Let it be that ... and that $f: \Omega^{'} \mapsto \Omega $ denotes a function". Does the "f" here actually mean Mapping? because you mentioned there is no "function" in your answer.

Comment: Sorry for my numerous comments, and thanks for your patience and numerous responses.

Comment: Yes $f$ is a function (or mapping if you like). Where did I mention that there is no function in my answer? In one of the comments I only remarked that in this context there is no *inverse function*.

Comment: oh , sorry about that, yes you mean no inverse function.